# inline if getting Scalar found where operator expected (I am not proficient with perl)

Tags: inline

Created a script that makes changes to a cable modem using snmp. Everything worked until I tried to add the ability to turn off WIFI if $wifi eq yes. Below is the portion of code I have.

The error begins on this line

```
if (!defined($wifi)) {
    $wifi = 'no';
    }

if ($model eq 'DG950A') {
    $result = $session->set_request(
       -varbindlist => [
          $oids{arrisRouterBssActive.12}, INTEGER, 2; if ($wifi eq 'yes')
          $oids{arrisRouterBssSSIDBroadcast.12}, INTEGER, 2 if ($wifii eq 'yes')
           $oids{arrisRouterRIPSendCMInterface}, INTEGER, 2,
         $oids{arrisRouterRIPAuthEnable}, INTEGER, 0,
         $oids{arrisRouterRIPRoutedSubnetEnable}, INTEGER, 1,
         $oids{arrisRouterRIPRoutedSubnetIP}, OCTET_STRING, hexip((split "/", $ip->first())[0]),
         $oids{arrisRouterRIPRoutedSubnetGWNetIP}, OCTET_STRING, hexip((split "/", $ip->first())[0]),
         $oids{arrisRouterRIPRoutedSubnetMask}, OCTET_STRING, hexip($mask),
           $oids{arrisRouterRIPEnable}, INTEGER, 1,
         $oids{arrisRouterFWEnabled}, INTEGER, 2,
         $oids{arrisRouterFWIPFloodDetect}, INTEGER, 2,
         $oids{arrisRouterFWAllowICMP}, INTEGER, 1,
         $oids{arrisRouterApplyAllSettings}, INTEGER, 1

        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the if statement up to the top if statement
was `if ($model eq 'DG950A') {
changed to`
if ($model eq 'DG950A' && $wifi eq 'yes') {